# Não consigo exibir minhas informações do banco de dados na página

Tags: php, mysql

Criei meu banco de dados **php**, fiz a conexão com o **mysql**, mas não aparece os dados que existem na minha tabela no *PhpMyAdmin*, o que aparece é isso:

```
" . resultado['nome'] ."
". resultado['email'] . "
". resultado['turno'] . "
" . resultado['uf'] . "
"; } ?>
```

...
Segue meu código abaixo:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$bd = "alunos";
$user = "root";
$senha = "";

$conexao = mysql_connect ($host, $user, $senha) or die (mysq_error());
mysql_select_db($bd, $conexao);

$tabela = msql_query("SELECT * FROM informacoes") ;
    while($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($tabela)){
       echo "informacoes:". $resultado['idaluno'] . "<br/>" . resultado['nome'] ."<br/>". resultado['email'] . "<br/>". resultado['turno'] . "<br/>" . resultado['uf'] . "<br/>";      
    }

?>
```

Comment: O nome da função está errado, é mysql_query e não msql_query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dois problemas veirificados:

1. Ausência do `$`.
2. Se esta exibindo o codigo fonte então o mesmo não esta sendo executado, verifique se esta acessando usando `localhost` (certo) ou `file:\\\` (errado).

Comment: Coloquei o $, e ficou assim: " . $resultado['nome'] ."
". $resultado['email'] . "
". $resultado['turno'] . "
" . $resultado['uf'] . "
"; } ?>

Comment: @RuanRodrigues e o segundo problema, verificou?

Comment: Verifiquei sim. Existe alguma coisa que pode atrapalhar a conexão do banco de dados? Tipo Firewall, antivírus, etc...

Comment: olha firewall nunca bloqueou minha conexão, e como ta a url esta do jeito certo ou errado?

Comment: file:///C:/wamp/www/banco%20de%20dados/html.html

Comment: Muda a extensão para .php, acesse pelo localhost

Comment: Muito Obrigado, ajudou bastante, lá pede para usar o mysqli... Mais meu problema por agora já foi resolvido. Agradeço.

Comment: Não tenho reputação suficiente para dar upvote ainda.

Answer (score 1):

As variaveis são acedidas com $ antes do nome: $resultado e nao resultado

Comment: Ficou assim: " . $resultado['nome'] ."
". $resultado['email'] . "
". $resultado['turno'] . "
" . $resultado['uf'] . "
"; } ?>